# any stronger test case to check code

Tags: c, binary-search

this code is getting a wrong answer in [spoj](http://www.spoj.com/problems/SUMFOUR/)
i want stronger test cases to check my code.. help appreciated..

The SUM problem can be formulated as follows: given four lists A, B, C, D of integer values, compute how many quadruplet (a, b, c, d ) belongs to A x B x C x D are such that a + b + c + d = 0 . In the following, we assume that all lists have the same size n

Input

The first line of the input file contains the size of the lists n (this value can be as large as 4000). We then have n lines containing four integer values (with absolute value as large as 2^28 ) that belong respectively to A, B, C and D .

Example

Input:

```
6
-45 22 42 -16
-41 -27 56 30
-36 53 -37 77
-36 30 -75 -46
26 -38 -10 62
-32 -54 -6 45
```

Output:

5

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int binarys(int a,long int b[],int low,int up,int k)
{
    int par;

    if(low <= up) {
        par = partition(low,up,b);
        if(b[par] + a == 0) {
            k = k + 1;
            k = binarys(a,b,low,par-1,k);
            k = binarys(a,b,par+1,up,k);
        }
        if(b[par] > -1*a)
            k = binarys(a,b,low,par-1,k);
        if(b[par] < -1*a)
            k = binarys(a,b,par+1,up,k);
    }
    return k;
}

int partition(int low,int up,int b[])
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int m;
    int a;

    j = low - 1;
    m = b[up];

    for(i=low; i < up; i++) {
        if(b[i] <= m ) {
            j++;
            a = b[i];
            b[i] = b[j];
            b[j] = a;
        }
    }
    a = b[j+1];
    b[j+1] = b[up];
    b[up] = a;

    return j + 1;
}

int main()
{
    long int *A = NULL;
    long int *B = NULL;
    long int *C = NULL;
    long int *D = NULL;
    long int *a = NULL;
    long int *b = NULL;
    int n;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int l;
    int sum;

    scanf("%d",&n);

    k = 0;
    sum = 0;
    A = (long int*)malloc(n*sizeof(long int));
    B = (long int*)malloc(n*sizeof(long int));
    C = (long int*)malloc(n*sizeof(long int));
    D = (long int*)malloc(n*sizeof(long int));
    a = (long int*)malloc(n*n*sizeof(long int));
    b = (long int*)malloc(n*n*sizeof(long int));

    for(i=0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d%d%d%d",&A[i],&B[i],&C[i],&D[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i < n; i++) {
        for(j=0; j < n; j++) {
            a[k] = A[i] + B[j];
            b[k] = C[i] + D[j];
            k++;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i < n*n; i++) {
        l = binarys(a[i],b,0,n*n,0);
        sum = sum + l;
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Compiling with gcc 4.7.2, -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow

```
a.c: In function ‘binarys’:
a.c:9:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘partition’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:75:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int *’ [-Wformat]
a.c:75:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int *’ [-Wformat]
a.c:75:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 4 has type ‘long int *’ [-Wformat]
a.c:75:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 5 has type ‘long int *’ [-Wformat]
```

### Your example test case

```
$ ./a
6
-45 22 42 -16
-41 -27 56 30
-36 53 -37 77
-36 30 -75 -46
26 -38 -10 62
-32 -54 -6 45
0$
```

It neither matches the expectation you provided (5), nor does it print a newline after the output. The grader may be expecting the newline and rejecting your program simply by you not writing it.

### Other basic test cases

```
$ ./a
1
0 0 0 0
2
```

Expected 1.

```
$ ./a
2
1 1 1 1
-3 100 100 100
0
```

Expected 1.

```
$ ./a
2
-1 2 2 2
-2 3 3 3
2
```

Expected 0.

```
$ ./a
1
9223372036854775807 -9223372036854775808 1 0   // LONG_MAX, LONG_MIN on my architecture
0
```

Expected 1.

```
$ ./a
0
0
```

Correct answer 0!